# Desgin convention regarding event handlers in VS c++ for MFC apps

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, mfc, event-handling

I have an overall design question relating to where event handlers are placed when developing MFC application in VS c++. Is it better to have event handlers in the Dialog class? Or is it acceptable to place event handlers in the main application class?

I ask this because I find myself trying to call functions in the main class from the dialog class, but then trying to update the GUI from the main class. I think it would be easier to move a majority of my code over to the GUI (dialog) class.

I suppose I am wondering what the convention is when it comes to event handling and calling functions that are not within the GUI where the event occurred.

Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it a dialog based application?

Comment: Yes it is a dialog based application. One dialog with a menu. The events are triggered from the menu as well as a few buttons, text boxes, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object-oriented design requires you to decide which objects are responsible for the various elements of your program.

A GUI class should be responsible for all interactions with the associated GUI element. In your case, the dialog class should handle all messages coming from the elements and menus embedded in the dialog.

Another class should probably be handling the representation of data within the program. This might be the application class or it could be a completely separate class. The Document/View architecture used by MFC is instructive - the application is only responsible for a few bookkeeping functions, the document class handles the data representation, and the view class is responsible for drawing the data in a window.